# Comparing streams

Tags: c++, stream

I'm looking into generalizing my data sources in my C++ application by using streams. However, my code also uses a resource manager that functions in a manner similar to a factory, except its primary purpose is to ensure that the same resource doesn't get loaded twice into memory.

```
myown::ifstream data("image.jpg");
std::ifstream data2("image2.jpeg");

ResourcePtr<Image> img1 = manager.acquire(data); 
ResourcePtr<Image> img2 = manager.acquire(data);

cout << img1 == img2; // True

ResourcePtr<Image> img3 = manager.acquire(data2);
cout << img1 == img3; // False
```

For it to do this, it obviously has to do some checks. Is there a reasonable way (readable and efficient) to implement this, if the resource manager has data streams as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The level of abstraction where the identity of the data is well above your streams.  Think about what your stream would do with that information if it knew it.  It could not act upon it, it is just a bunch of data.  In terms of the interface, a stream doesn't necessarily even have an end.  You would be violating least surprise for me if you tried to tie identity to it at that level.

That sounds like a reasonable abstraction for your `ResourcePtr`, though.  You could hash the data when you load it into `ResourcePtr`, but a key on the file path is probably just as good.

Comment: Hashing seems like a good solution. I can't use the path as a key because the data comes from a virtual file system, it doesn't have a path _per se_.

Comment: @Paul It could be based on the virtual file system path as well, whatever is unique. I assume these resources are static, not changing at run time. Hash would be good when you have the same data coming from disparate places, which do not know about each other. If it's always the same data and always the same location in the virtual file system, then I would say a hash is overboard. It is a trade off, do whatever is simplest per your environment.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot "compare" data streams. Streams are not containers; they are *flows of data*.

---

BTW, `cout << a == b` is `(cout << a) == b`; I think you meant `cout << (a==b)`.

Comment: How come cout << a == b is equal to (cout << a) == b?  I would have thought it would have been the same as the parenthesis version since you usually read right-to-left.  I'm not arguing, I'd just like to understand it better :)

Comment: @w00te: Different operators have different "precedence". It's not as simple as right-to-left. (And, really, you should say "equivalent" not "equal".)

Comment: I understand precedence in most scenarios.  I'm surprised that the stream insertion takes precedence over an equality comparison though.  I checked http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence and don't see stream insertion operators as part of the preference list so that's why I was asking why they take precedence.

Comment: @w00te: `<<` started off life as left-shift. It's not really a stream operator; iostreams just sort of stole it. Look at line 7 in that table.

Answer (score 0):

Like Tomalak said, you can't compare streams. You'll have to wrap them in some class which associates an ID to them, possibly based on the absolute path if they are all associated to files on the file system